# Spring AOP turns off Spring Security Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, aop

I want to run MyAspect first, before Spring Security PreAuthorize, when I put Order(0) on my Aspect, PreAuthorize is ignored, spring security doesn't evalute conditions, without this Order(0), Spring security PreAuthorize is invoked first and it missess some id that should be filled with MyAspect aspect:

```
@Named
@Aspect
@Configuration
@Order(0)
public class MyAspect {

    @Around("execution(* mypackage.MyRepo.save(..))")
    public void tessst(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    }
}
```

**MyRepo**

```
   @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SOME_AUTHORITY') and hasPermission(blablabla)")
    public MyObject save(@Param("argument") MyObject myObject) {
       //code
    }
```

Comment: Show your method security configuration.

Comment: You are waiting for an answer for 3 weeks now. This might be an indicator that an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful, ideally in GitHub for everyone to reproduce the problem.